# npm can not publish my module

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-publish

I am trying to publish my module to see how it works.

I installed npm and then created my very simple module.

I used `npm add user` to add myself as a new user. I received the following message: `Logged in as david1994 on https://registry.npmjs.org/`

Then I tried to publish my module with `npm publish`, but I got the following error:

```
npm ERR! code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR! syscall: 'open',
npm ERR! path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\supermodule\\npm-debug.log.1866747129' }
```

But I can not see any `npm-debug.log` in my module directory.

Comment: 1) Might it be a hidden file? 2) Are you able to access the file?

Comment: can you install packages from npm registry?

Comment: @Venky, I installed npm.

Comment: @Scimonster, I checked the file but there is not log file in my directory. I opened hidden files and folders. Still no result. I can add user, because after I add I can login in npm.org but I can not do "npm publish"

Comment: What does your `package.json` look like?

Comment: Here is my package.json file:                                                                          {
  "name": "supermodule",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}

Comment: Read this. Hope helpful 
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8561

Answer (score 5):

Possible it looks like a module with that name was already published by someone else, so you'd need to use a different name, or use a scope if you really want to keep the same name.

could you check that the name is not already taken by someone else, as well?

[read more](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8561)

Answer (score 0):

The EPERM error indicates that there is a problem opening a file as the `npm publish` command does not seem to have permission to access to that file.

The name of the file giving you the problem should be found in the report file ...

```
debug.log.1866747129
```

in the following directory ...

C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\supermodule\

If for some reason you cannot access the above file run the publish step again using `--dd` flag which will increase the amount of logging that you see on the screen should help you troubleshoot your problem

See [npm config](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config) for a full list of command line parameters that can help you troubleshoot this problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not find any log file in the directory you mentioned. Now trying to publish I have the following:                                              npm ERR! you do not have permission
as the correct user? : supermodule

Comment: Have you tried running cmd or powershell as Administrator; Right Click then select Run As Administrator.